# Sum over a column and remove duplicates simultaneously

Tags: r

```
FromUser   To User  Weight
U1          U3       1
U2          U4       2
U3          U2       1
U1          U3       0.5
U2          U4       -1
```

I have the following DF in R.

```
FromUser   To User  Weight
U1          U3       1
U2          U4       2
U3          U2       1
U1          U3       0.5
U2          U4       -1
```

As you can see there are duplicates in terms of fron-to-to interaction. I want to create a df with unique from and to users with weights as sum of weights. So the updated table based on above should look like

```
FromUser   To User  Weight
U1          U3       1.5
U2          U4       1
U3          U2       1
```

I am not sure how to go about this. I am sure there is a novel dplyr soln, but cant seem to find it.

Comment: `df %>% group_by(FromUser, ToUser) %>% summarise(Weight = sum(Weight))`

Comment: I think this is a better dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group